# Not retrieving .notConnectedToInternet URLSession

Tags: swift, urlsession

So I'm trying to get URLSession URLError.code `.notConnectedToInternet` but all I'm getting is `Code(rawValue: -1020)` when using URLSession when disconnecting from the internet.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
       if let error = error {
          print("error.code \((error as! URLError).code)")
          //prints - error.code Code(rawValue: -1020)
            
            if (error as! URLError).code == .notConnectedToInternet {
                print("no internet")
                //doesn't print
                return
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error code -1020` means `dataNotAllowed`. It means the connection failed because data use isn’t currently allowed on the device.

What you are trying to catch `notConnectedToInternet` `error code -1009` means connection failed because the device isn’t connected to the internet.

So `notConnectedToInternet` is not same as `dataNotAllowed`. In this case check your device settings.

Comment: So in device settings there is an option for my app to allow access to local network. Switching this off got me the `.notConnectedToInternet` error for URLSession.